# Should I pass object in method parameter or in parent constructor in Java

Tags: java, oop, dependency-injection, guice, discord-jda

I have a dilemma in mind that I can't solve.
Should I pass object in method parameter or in parent constructor in this case ?

First idea:

```java
public class TempChannelsPlugin extends JolssyPlugin {

    private JDA client;
    private TempChannelsListener listener;
    private JdaCommandManager jdaCommandManager;

    @Inject
    public TempChannelsPlugin(JDA client, JdaCommandManager jdaCommandManager, TempChannelsListener listener) {
        super(Category.UTILITIES, "Temporary Channels");

        this.client = client;
        this.jdaCommandManager = jdaCommandManager;
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    @Override
    protected void setup() {
        this.registerListener(this.client, this.listener);
    }
}
```

And in JolssyPlugin:

```java
protected void registerListener(JDA client, ListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
   this.registerListeners(client, listenerAdapter);
}
```

Second idea:

```java
public class TempChannelsPlugin extends JolssyPlugin {

    private JDA client;
    private TempChannelsListener listener;
    private JdaCommandManager jdaCommandManager;

    @Inject
    public TempChannelsPlugin(JDA client, JdaCommandManager jdaCommandManager, TempChannelsListener listener) {
        super(client, Category.UTILITIES, "Temporary Channels");

        this.jdaCommandManager = jdaCommandManager;
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    @Override
    protected void setup() {
        this.registerListener(this.listener);
    }
}
```

And in JolssyPlugin:

```java
protected void registerListener(ListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
   this.registerListeners(this.client, listenerAdapter);
}
```

What is the difference between these two cases? And why should I favor one case over another?

Notice that I'm using Guice for DI

Comment: Perhaps you should explain your reservations or concerns about either approach.

Answer (score 2):

In my view, if method `registerListener(ListenerAdapter listenerAdapter)` is located into `TempChannelsPlugin` class:

```
protected void registerListener(ListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
   this.registerListeners(this.client, listenerAdapter);
}
```

then the second option is better as vatiable `private JDA client;` has a scope for the whole class. So there is no need to declare unnecessary parameter because we can use `private JDA client;` variable in any place of class `TempChannelsPlugin`.

### UPDATE:

In my view, if method `registerListener(ListenerAdapter listenerAdapter)` is located to `TempChannelsPlugin` class, then the second option is better as vatiable `private JDA client;` has a scope for the whole class.
So there is no need to declare unnecessary parameter.

I would mode dependency of `JDA client` to `JolssyPlugin` as you have `registerListener` in `JolssyPlugin`.
By doing this we can remove one parameter from methods such as `registerListener` and `registerListeners`.
So code would look like this:

```
public abstract class JolssyPlugin {

    protected Set<ListenerAdapter> listeners = new HashSet<>();

    protected JdaCommandManager jdaCommandManager;
    protected Category category;
    protected String name;
    private JDA jdaClient;

    public JolssyPlugin(Category category, String name, JDA jdaClient) {
        this.category = category;
        this.name = name;
        this.jdaClient = jdaClient;
    }
    
    protected abstract void setup();

    protected void registerListener( ListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
       this.registerListeners(client, listenerAdapter);
    }

    protected void registerListeners(ListenerAdapter... listenerAdapter) {
        List<ListenerAdapter> listeners = Arrays.asList(listenerAdapter);

        client.addEventListener(listeners);
        this.listeners.addAll(listeners);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D `registerListener` is located into `JolssyPlugin`

Comment: @FlavioMoreno could you show, please, the whole code of `JolssyPlugin`?

Comment: Yes: https://hastebin.com/ijaxejiwor.java

Comment: @FlavioMoreno Please, see my updated answer